# How to I play videos in TVML?

Tags: video, tvml, onselect

I am trying to get video to work in the TVML Catalog template. I have added the following code to the application.js file:

```
function playMedia(extension, mediaType) {
var videourl = baseURL + extension;
var singleVideo = new MediaItem(mediaType, videourl);
var videoList = new Playlist();
videoList.push(singleVideo);
var myPlayer = new Player();
myPlayer.playlist = videoList;
myPlayer.play();
}
```

in my lockup, I have the following:

```
lockup onselect="playMedia('video', 'https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/basic-stream-osx-ios4-3.html')>
```

When I run the project, I click on the lockup item and nothing plays. Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

it must be because of the video's url?

You have `https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/basic-stream-osx-ios4-3.html`, which doesn't seem to be a valid video. Try `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4`?

you can add the eventlistener on the video player to get more info on why it failed. Like this:

```
        myPlayer.addEventListener('playbackError', function(event){
                                   console.log(event.reason)
                                   });
```

as described in the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmljs/player/1682115-playbackerror).